# PHP basic syntax

Tags: php, syntax

Good day. Why is it possible to write a php statement like this?

```
<?php if (is_home()) { ?>
//some code
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate. Why do you think it should not be allowed?

Comment: nice question... I think Mr. Lardorf would surely give you an award for this.

Comment: Any reason why you think it shouldn't be possible? Any reason why you haven't tried it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

PHP was actually first designed as a templating language. More about the history of [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/history.php) here (which is very interesting to read) :).

For example, in PHP 2 and below, the syntax looked like this:

```
<!--include /text/header.html-->

<!--getenv HTTP_USER_AGENT-->
<!--ifsubstr $exec_result Mozilla-->
  Hey, you are using Netscape!<p>
<!--endif-->

<!--sql database select * from table where user='$username'-->
<!--ifless $numentries 1-->
  Sorry, that record does not exist<p>
<!--endif exit-->
  Welcome <!--$user-->!<p>
  You have <!--$index:0--> credits left in your account.<p>

<!--include /text/footer.html-->
```

My thought is that people found this type of templating language to be very easy to use and very easy to understand. As PHP improved and became more like a conventional language as well as received OOP functionality, "templating" remained by allowing you to mix PHP code and HTML markup using `<?php ?>` to enclose your PHP code.

So, the interpreter would only evaluate the bits of code between `<?php ?>`, leave the stuff outside of those tags alone, then send that out to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The web page is processed top down by the server's php interpreter.

if that was the entirety of your web page, the interpreter would kick in on line 1 and process the if, the code block then follows (ie the open brace)  then php interpretation pauses while everything between the braces is held in a buffer. the processor continues once it finds line three and can close the block.

now that it has all the data it needs, it can (if the condition is true) either output the '//some code' text (because it isn't actually code, it's just plain html) or output nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is admittedly a little weird because although `//some code` is not part of the PHP code, it is still dependent on its flow statements.

It makes it more clear to think of `?>` and `<?php` not as the closing and opening tags for PHP, but as the opening and closing tags of the intermixed html/text.

`?> // some code <?php` is effectively the same as `echo "//some code";`